# Why Apple FaceTime HD camera does not offer MJPEG/DMB1 pixel format

Tags: camera, video-streaming, avfoundation, macos-catalina

I've been trying to deploy CoreMediaIO framework to capture Mac builtin camera stream:

```cpp
  OSStatus result;
  UInt32 dataSize;
  CMIOObjectPropertyAddress opa = {kCMIOObjectPropertyClass,
                                   kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, 0};

  opa.mSelector = kCMIOStreamPropertyDirection;
  UInt32 direction;
  result = CMIOObjectGetPropertyData(objectID, &opa, 0, NULL, sizeof(UInt32),
                                     &dataSize, &direction);
  if (result != 0) {
    printf("Error getting kCMIOStreamPropertyDirection for stream\n");
    return;
  }
  printf("Stream is %s\n", direction == 0 ? "output" : "input");
  opa.mSelector = kCMIOStreamPropertyFormatDescriptions;
  CFArrayRef streamDescriptions = NULL;
  if (CMIOObjectHasProperty(objectID, &opa)) {
    printf("Stream offers multiple formats\n");
    result =
        CMIOObjectGetPropertyData(objectID, &opa, 0, NULL, sizeof(CFArrayRef),
                                  &dataSize, &streamDescriptions);
    if (result != 0) {
      printf("Error in CMIOObjectGetPropertyData for stream\n");
      return;
    }
  }
```

Surprisingly, there are only YUV formats offered:

```
"<CMVideoFormatDescription 0x7fd360c0f970 [0x7fff8b4d1b60]> {\n\tmediaType:'vide' \n\tmediaSubType:'2vuy' \n\tmediaSpecific: {\n\t\tcodecType: '2vuy'\t\tdimensions: 160 x 120 \n\t} \n\textensions: {{\n    CVBytesPerRow = 320;\n    CVFieldCount = 1;\n    CVImageBufferColorPrimaries = \"ITU_R_709_2\";\n    CVImageBufferTransferFunction = \"ITU_R_709_2\";\n    CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix = \"ITU_R_709_2\";\n    FormatName = \"Y'CbCr 4:2:2 - uyvy\";\n    \"com.apple.cmio.format_extension.video.only_has_i_frames\" = 1;\n}}\n}",
```

Obviously, camera sensor hardware does support MJPEG frame format. But why is it unavailable in CoreMediaIO framework?

Comment: `Obviously, camera sensor hardware does support MJPEG frame format.` Why is that Obvious? I doubt it is true. You can capture the raw pixels and encode it to MJPEG.

Comment: It's obvious because 30fps is impossible for raw pixels in 720P on USB2. That's why I don't simply encode - the FPS rate is lost. Also for this particular case I know for sure that MJPEG is supported through the libusb.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a CMIO driver for exposing MJPEG formatt

Comment: Given the unknown amount of camera sensors that could be introduced by Apple, this does not seem feasible. However, do you imply that MJPEG format does not exist in CMIO?